# I cannot compile the Slingswarm package from GitHub on Debian 8

Tags: compiling, slingshot-launcher

I don't find an answer on the web. '-'

```
$ cmake ..

-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.28") 
-- checking for modules 'gtk+-3.0;gee-0.8;gio-unix-2.0;libgnome-menu
3.0'
--   found gtk+-3.0, version 3.14.5
--   found gee-0.8, version 0.16.1
--   found gio-unix-2.0, version 2.42.1
--   found libgnome-menu-3.0, version 3.13.3
-- checking for module 'gthread-2.0 >= 2.14.0'
--   found gthread-2.0 , version 2.42.1
-- Found Vala: /usr/bin/valac  
-- checking for a minimum Vala version of 0.14.0
--   found Vala, version 0.26.1
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /usr/local/slingswarm/build

$ make

[ 11%] Generating slingshot.c, frontend/widgets/AppItem.c, frontend/widgets/CompositedWindow.c, frontend/widgets/Indicators.c, frontend/widgets/Searchbar.c, frontend/Utilities.c, frontend/Color.c, backend/GMenuEntries.c
/usr/local/slingswarm/slingshot.vala:167.17-167.45: error: 2 missing arguments for `void Gtk.Grid.attach (Gtk.Widget child, int left, int top, int width, int height)'
                this.grid.attach (item, c, r);
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
CMakeFiles/slingswarm-launcher.dir/build.make:60: recipe for target 'slingshot.c' failed
make[2]: *** [slingshot.c] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:60: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/slingswarm-launcher.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/slingswarm-launcher.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

https://github.com/echo-devim/slingswarm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slingswarm expects newer versions of `valac` than 0.26.1; later versions define default values for the missing parameters to [`Gtk.Grid.attach`](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Grid.attach.html). To build the package on Debian 8, change the erroneous line in `slingshot.vala` to

```
this.grid.attach (item, c, r, 1, 1);
```

and run `make` again.

(So really this is a bug in Slingswarm.)

Comment: This works, but now `make install` doesn't: `file INSTALL cannot copy file "/usr/local/slingswarm/usr/slingswarm-launcher.desktop" to "/usr/share/applications/slingswarm-launcher.desktop"`

Comment: You need to run `make install` as root, *e.g.* using `sudo make install`.

Comment: This works! Much love bro.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the new proyect for that: https://github.com/libredeb/lightpad is optimized for raspbian armhf, fedora and ubuntu distros. Regards!